# javascript source code change detection

Tags: javascript, ajax, security, web

I'm wondering if there is a way to detect the source code of javascript file that I'm using on my web site has changed? I am using ajax inside of it and I feel like it should me more secure since the code could easily be changed. I can do something like everytime the php file opens it could download the js file and check manually if code has changed with the help of some if else structures. But would it be healthy?

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Just as I said on the first sentence; If client changes the js code is there a way to detect it?

Comment: Ah ok! i didn't understood that you were trying to check file modification on client side. You wanna know if someone is trying to modify the js code provided by a website in his browser?

Comment: Yes that's it and I think I found a way to do it

Comment: Feel free to share it

Comment: Check the str's comment below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like you are looking for [Subresource Integrity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Subresource_Integrity).

> Subresource Integrity (SRI) is a security feature that enables browsers to verify that files they fetch (for example, from a CDN) are delivered without unexpected manipulation. It works by allowing you to provide a cryptographic hash that a fetched file must match.

Using that technology, you can define a hash that your scripts are checked against. If they do not match, the scripts are not executed. For example:

```
<script src="https://example.com/example-framework.js"
        integrity="sha384-oqVuAfXRKap7fdgcCY5uykM6+R9GqQ8K/uxy9rx7HNQlGYl1kPzQho1wx4JwY8wC"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Note, however, that the [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=subresource-integrity) currently is not that great.

Comment: That's actually what I'm exactly looking for, thanks